# Can't make Retryable / Recover verify work in Spring Boot Unit Tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test, spring-retry

I have a very simple setup for calling an external service and retrying 3 times but I just can't make my Tests to work with Retryable.
In my tests my method only gets called 1 time and stops even though when starting the app and testing it with Postman I get the retries working correctly. Can anyone spot what's wrong?
These are my classes:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableRetry
public class ChallengeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ChallengeApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ChallengeApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class RetryableInterestService {

    final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    protected Double lastResult = null;
    RetryableInterestService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
    String uri = "http://localhost:8082/api/interest";
    @Retryable(value = {RestClientException.class}, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(200))
    public Double callInterestService() {
        log.info("Calling Interest service using uri: " + uri);
        lastResult = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Double.class);
        return lastResult;
    }

    @Recover
    public Double returnLastValue() throws ExternalApiCallException {
        log.info("Returning last stored value: " + lastResult);
        if(lastResult != null) {
            return lastResult;
        } else {
            throw new ExternalApiCallException("There wasn't a backup Interest value to return");
        }
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ChallengeApplicationTests.class})
public class RetryableInterestServiceTest {
    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @InjectMocks
    RetryableInterestService retryableInterestService;

    @Test
    void whenCallInterestService_shouldReturnDouble() {
        when(restTemplate.getForObject(anyString(), any())).thenReturn(10.0);
        Double result = retryableInterestService.callInterestService();
        assertEquals(result, 10.0);
    }

    @Test
    void givenException_whenCallInterestService_shouldRetry() {
        when(restTemplate.getForObject(anyString(), any()))
                .thenThrow(new RestClientException(""))
                .thenThrow(new RestClientException(""))
                .thenReturn(10.0);
        Double result = retryableInterestService.callInterestService();
        verify(restTemplate, times(3)).getForObject(any(), any());
    }
}
```

I've tried adding @EnableRetry on RetryableInterestServiceTest and on ChallengeApplicationTests but it won't work. I always get the one call and it ends on the Exception and no retries.
If I try:

```
   Exception exception = assertThrows(RestClientException.class, () -> {
       retryableInterestService.callInterestService();
   });
```

I get a failed test because verify checks the method is only called once and fails.

Comment: Any lucky trying `@MockBean` instead on RestTemplate and no longer using `@InjectMocks`? May still need `@EnableRetry` as well.

Comment: The `RetryableInterestService` must be managed by Spring (not Mockito) for `Retryable` to work; use `@Autowired` instead.

Comment: Using `@MockBean` like scrhartley recommended and using `@Autowired` like @Gary Russell recommended did the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you are using `@Mock`/`@InjectMocks`, then it is not a Spring Boot test